# Android studio me autocompletion text view

Tags: java, xml

I want to develop an Android app in android studio.
I'm creating a "search train between station" and I want the solution when I enter a station name in a textfield then all the station names and codes appear from the entered keyword.
For example.. when I enter p then all station name and code of p appears.
How do I do it? Please tell me.
How do I get suggestions of the station name along with station code please help me.

I am doing this in Android studio and I have xml file and java file